# How to stream from Streamlabs mobile app to Red5 via RTMP

Tags: rtmp, red5

I'm trying to stream video from my phone and I want to be able to see it on my computer. I got the Streamlabs app on my iPhone and saw I could run an RTMP server which would have lower latency than YouTube for example. I found out about Red5 and ran it on Ubuntu. Streamslabs asks for a url and stream key. I'm assuming the url is the public ip of my computer.

The problem is that I have no idea how to get the stream key. There is no place that simply says how to setup RTMP so I can watch a stream. All I see is how to setup RTMPS which still doesn't even show how to setup a stream on the [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/wiki/RTMPS). Yes, I forwarded the RTMP port (1935). I just need to figure out how to set the stream up. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When asked for url and stream key the application would normal want the url to your server which would look something like this: `rtmp://my_server_ip:1935/live` replace `my_server_ip` with your server's IP address or fqdn. For stream key, they want your stream name, usually so let's say your stream name is `redstone`; fill those in and hit publish or start on the app and you should be good to go.